# What's the recommended way to populate a model from a viewModel in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following class:

```
   public class City {
      public string key1 {get; set; }
      public string key2 { get; set; }
      public string col1 { get; set; }
      public string col2 { get; set; }
      public int newplusnew2 { get; set; }
   }
```

a viewmodel:

```
   public class CityViewModel {
      public City city { get; set; }
      public int new1 { get; set; }
      public int new1 { get; set; }
   }
```

an action:

```
 public JsonResult JsonCreate(CityViewModel viewModel)
        {

 //  Validation checks go here

            var model = new City ();
            ???

   }
```

Can someone tell me the best way for me to populate the four string columns and the int column from the viewmodel? I just want to know
if there is some recommended way to do this.

Comment: ehm, if I understand correctly, your getting a `CityViewModel` back from a postback, and you need to get `City out`... but af far as a can see, `CityViewModel` already contain a `City` object, so you just can do `City model = viewModel.city`

Comment: can't see any other replying, so I'll put it as an answer, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your getting a `CityViewModel` back from a postback, and you need to get `City` out... but af far as a can see, `CityViewModel` already contain a `City` object, so you just can do:

```
public JsonResult JsonCreate(CityViewModel viewModel)
{
    //  Validation checks go here
    var model = viewModel.city;
}
```